# Creating win32api(dll) that will be callable on another language

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

How can I create win32api(dll) that will be callable on another language? Example:

When I'm using ruby, I should use my dll which written on C# or C++. So how can I create a dynamic library like that?

Comment: Most any language runtime on Windows supports a C api or a COM Automation interface.  Ruby is no exception through its ffi interop layer, pick your poison.

Comment: Basically any DLL you make should be callable from ruby, so just make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are important differences between C++ and C# Dlls.

The C++ ones allow you to expose global functions (using `__declspec(dllexport`)) that you can call from ruby.

C# Dlls contain a manifest that can be used to find all the types and use the entire object model from said Dll.

I have never tried the later (i.e. all types and class hierarchy) using ruby, but, if possible, it would be a preferred approach to being able to call only the exported functions.
IronRuby apparently has no issues importing .NET types.

To create a C++ library select Visual C++ Win32 project, and then press Next on ensuing dialog to check DLL checkbox. Otherwise select Visual C# Class Library project.

Comment: So impossible to call c# function from ruby? I tried to call c# compiled library but it gets error like "getprocaddress" on ruby.

Comment: Not necessarily. But remember that in C# there are no global functions like in C++. Functions are always members of a class/object. If function is static, you may be able to call it without instantiating the instance of the object first.

Comment: Also you would not use GetProcAddress on C# functions. That is only for C++ (actually C) global functions that are not any class members or are static class members.

Comment: My functions which in c# library, was not static. So we can say that it is problem, right?

Comment: Yes, that's a start. However, in ruby you should have a way to 'import' the class hierarchy from C# library. That is probably not going to use GetProcAddress.

Comment: I didn't use anything like GetProcAddress on c# library. I compiled my library on visual studio and when I tried to call it on ruby, it made error like : GetProcAddress:get_func and get_funcA

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33012/discussion-between-ali-avci-and-tony)

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods.

1. If your DLL is implemented using native language, such as C/C++. You can export C Function from your DLL and call it on other language. Most languages are able to call C Function either directly or using language extension, such as `Win32API` in Ruby.
2. Use COM (Component Object Model). COM is designed to work across languages. This is preferred method because it has many advantages. You can implement COM Class using C#, C++, Delphi and other languages and use it in other language like normal object in that language.